# How to use filter() on a multidimensional array using values from another array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, filter

I have a multidimensional array:

```
var arr1 = 
  [
  [["John"],[50],["Solar"],["Egypt"]],
  [["Joe"],[60],["Wind"],["Ghana"]],
  [["Alan"],[70],["Coal"],["Nigeria"]]
  ]
```

And another array of filter values:

```
var arr2 = ["Solar","Wind"]
```

I want to filter arr1 using values from arr2. So the result should be an array:

```
var results = 
  [
  [["John"],[50],["Solar"],["Egypt"]],
  [["Joe"],[60],["Wind"],["Ghana"]]
  ]
```

How can I use .filter() to achieve this? I tried this already but didn't work:

```
var filtered = var filtered = arr1.filter(function(e) {
  return e[2] == arr2
}
);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27448016/1101930

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter an array from all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34901593/how-to-filter-an-array-from-all-elements-of-another-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, that's not the way you check if a value exists in an array. Within the context of Google Apps Script, you should use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39317252/what-functions-do-arrays-in-google-apps-script-support) for which array methods are supported).

When you compare `e[2] == arr2`, you're actually checking if `["Solar"] == ["Solar","Wind"]`. Clearly, it's not the same. So you need to check if `e[2][0]`, which is just "Solar", exists in the filter array. Using `arr2.indexOf(e[2][0])` will return the index of where "Solar" exists in the array; if the value doesn't exist, it will return `-1`. So all you need to do is check for that `-1`.

If you can assume that the filter values will always be in the third position, then you can use this fairly simple implementation.

```
var arr1 = [
  [["John"],[50],["Solar"],["Egypt"]],
  [["Joe"],[60],["Wind"],["Ghana"]],
  [["Alan"],[70],["Coal"],["Nigeria"]]
];
var arr2 = ["Solar","Wind"];
var result = arr1.filter(function(e) {
  return arr2.indexOf(e[2][0]) != -1;
});
Logger.log(result);
```

Otherwise, you need to check all of the elements of the array. This approach assumes that all of the values are wrapped in their own array, so it extracts them into a single array using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can then use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check against all of the filter values.

```
var arr1 = [
  [["John"],[50],["Solar"],["Egypt"]],
  [["Joe"],[60],["Wind"],["Ghana"]],
  [["Alan"],[70],["Coal"],["Nigeria"]]
];
var arr2 = ["Solar","Wind"];  
var result = arr1.filter(function(e) {
  var joined = e.map(function(element) { return element[0] });
  return arr2.some(function(filterVal) { return joined.indexOf(filterVal) != -1});
});
Logger.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the first array. In the callback for each nested array, [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)ten it and check to see if if [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the elements from the second array are included in it.

Edit: Updated answer as App Scripts doesn't support ES6.

```js
const arr1 = [
  [["John"],[50],["Solar"], ["Egypt"]],
  [["Joe"],[60],["Wind"],["Ghana"]],
  [["Alan"],[70],["Coal"],["Nigeria"]]
];

const arr2 = ["Solar", "Wind"];

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (acc, val) {
    return acc.concat(val);
  }, []);
}

const out = arr1.filter(function (arr) {
  return arr2.some(function (el) {
    return flatten(arr).indexOf(el) > -1;
  });
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: I'm using Google Apps Script which doesn't allow the use of .flat()

Comment: @AjayUbhi, I've amended my answer slightly.

Comment: For future reference, apps script is currently ES5. So, no `...`,`=>` or `flat`, `flatMap`, `Array.from` or other ES6 features

Comment: @TheMaster, I didn't know that. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I see you edited your answer. I know that it's a pain, but as said in my previous comment , `=>` arrows aren't supported either.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [
  [
    ["John"],
    [50],
    ["Solar"],
    ["Egypt"]
  ],
  [
    ["Joe"],
    [60],
    ["Wind"],
    ["Ghana"]
  ],
  [
    ["Alan"],
    [70],
    ["Coal"],
    ["Nigeria"]
  ]
];
var arr2 = ["Solar", "Wind"];
var filtered = arr1.filter(a1 => arr2.some(a2 => a2 === a1[2][0]));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your data is structured the way it is, but here is a way you could go about it:

```js
var arr1 = 
  [
  [["John"],[50],["Solar"],["Egypt"]],
  [["Joe"],[60],["Wind"],["Ghana"]],
  [["Alan"],[70],["Coal"],["Nigeria"]]
  ]
  
 var arr2 = ["Solar", "Wind"]
 
 console.log(arr1.filter(item => item.flatMap(d => d).some(s => arr2.includes(s))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't assume the order of your first array's elements. Though, it does assume each sub element (i.e. `["Solar"]`) only contains one element.

```js
var arr1 = 
  [
  [["John"],[50],["Solar"],["Egypt"]],
  [["Joe"],[60],["Wind"],["Ghana"]],
  [["Alan"],[70],["Coal"],["Nigeria"]]
  ]


var arr2 = ["Solar","Wind"]

let result = arr1.filter(el1 => {
  return arr2.some(el2 => el1.find(x => x[0] === el2))
})

console.log(result)
```